# using the user info in the vendor files

Tags: php, laravel

hi i have a package that logs the info into a table in database and i want to add the user id that is doing that action which is payment to that package now my question is that how can i access user_id in the vendor folder ?? here is the code it inserts below :

```
$this->transactionId = $this->getTable()->insert([
            'id'            => $uid,
            'port'          => $this->getPortName(),
            'price'         => $this->amount,
            'status'        => Enum::TRANSACTION_INIT,
            'ip'            => Request::getClientIp(),
            'description'   => $this->description,
            'created_at'    => Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at'    => Carbon::now(),
        ]) ? $uid : null;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in the vendor folder"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You may access the authenticated user via the Auth facade:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

// Get the currently authenticated user...

$user = Auth::user();

// Get the currently authenticated user's ID...

$id = Auth::id();
```

**You may access the authenticated user via an Illuminate\Http\Request**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function someFunctionName(Request $request)
{
     $request->user(); //returns an instance of the authenticated user...
     $request->user()->id; // returns authenticated user id. 
}
```

**via the Auth helper function:**

```
auth()->user();  //returns an instance of the authenticated user...
auth()->user()->id ; // returns authenticated user id.
```